# Excel - Conditional Sumproduct to select specific criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have a set of data that consists of a column of cost data, and then a table of allocations across categories (i.e. column headers are different categories, table contents are % allocations across those categories). Each cost data point has an allocation across the different categories.

I am trying to dynamically isolate the total cost for each category. So far I have tried using `=sumproduct(cost_column,if(category_headers=category,category_table,))`

where

cost_column = column of cost data

category_headers = row at the top of the table of allocations

category_table = table of % allocations (excl. headers)

I am entering this as an array function, but it is returning a #VALUE error.

Is there anyway that I can dynamically calculate the total cost per category? Essentially I am trying to limit the category_table array to be the same size as the cost_column array.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Example image here [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoqcV.png)

Comment: It's easier to understand with some sample data and sample of desired result.

Comment: How many categories are there?

Comment: @P.b I have attached an example image. The desired result is the "Cost per Category" table

Comment: @JSmart523 there are 70+ categories and 10 years of monthly cost data - but the number of categories should be irrelevant for this question, no? I would expect the answer to be the same regardless of whether there are 3 categories or 1,000.

Comment: Well, if there were only three categories then a dumb, brute force, hardcoded or manual approach would be better because it would be manageable and simpler. With over 70 categories, looping makes much more sense.

Comment: @JSmart523 Ah gotcha - agreed. I want it to be dynamic a) to directly transpose the data and b) to avoid massively inflating the workbook size. This is also a dataset that is likely to change frequently, so prefer to have it be dynamic if possible

Comment: How would Excel know which columns are category columns? "All but first 2 columns"? "Every column with a column title that ends with '%'”?

Comment: @JSmart523 The category and cost data are in different tables, so would be captured in different arrays. But the latter (everything ending in %) would work as well.

Comment: How do you calculate the values in the table? Can you show an example for let's say `196,33`?

Comment: @OverflowStacker I just manually calculated those for reference - for 196.33, that is the sumproduct of the 1/31/21 cost column and the category A allocation column, i.e. formula is =sumproduct(D6:D15,I6:15) EDIT: to clarify the ask, essentially what I am looking for is a conditional to replace the "I6:I15" that selects the entire allocation array (i.e. I6:K15) and conditionally reduces it to I6:I15, J6:J15, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this non-volatile solution: `=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($D$6:$G$15,,MATCH(D$18,$D$5:$G$5,0)),INDEX($I$6:$K$15,,MATCH($C19,$I$5:$K$5,0)))`
This will not recalculate at every change in any cell of the workbook, like for instance `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT`, which may slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
     (OFFSET($C$6:$C$15,,MATCH(D$18,$D$5:$G$5,0)))
    *(OFFSET($H$6:$H$15,,MATCH($C19,$I$5:$K$5,0)))
 )
```

and let me know, if it works for you or not.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm. I was just about to post a different solution using indirect(address(match())) but this is much more elegant